# How to Extract fields from array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
let obj = [{ first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe'  , x : 1 },
          { first: 'Jane1', last: 'Doe1', x : 2 },
          { first: 'Jane2', last: 'Doe2', x : 3 },
          { first: 'Jane3', last: 'Doe4' , x : 4}];
          
          // gives false for unsatisfied condition, which is fine I believe
          let res = obj.map( o =>  {  return o.x > 2 && {  "first": o.first, "x": o.x  }  } )
          // below returns all fields where as I want only two fields
          let res1 = obj.filter( o => {  return o.x > 2 && {  "first": o.first, "x": o.x  } } )
          
console.log(res)
console.log(res1)
```

How to get first and x fields with condition

Expected output

```
[
   {
    "first": "Jane2",
    "x": 3
  },
  {
    "first": "Jane3",
    "x": 4
  }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `&& {  "first": o.first, "x": o.x  }` does? I expect it to return the truthy value of "yes it is an object"

Comment: what are your "desired fields" you want to get?

Comment: I want to put if inside there , could not get so tried &&

Comment: @NickParsons in return statement

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam so you want an array of objects which only has your first and x keys in them?

Comment: You can do `return o.x > 2 && o.first==="Jane"` but you likely need to tell us more - show expected output

Comment: Post updated with required output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.reduce` to form an array of objects where x is greater than 2 like so. Here I have used [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the `first` and `x` property from the given object, and then used a ternary operator to check whether or not to add the object to the array:

```js
const arr = [{first:'Jane',last:'Doe',x:1},{first:'Jane1',last:'Doe1',x:2},{first:'Jane2',last:'Doe2',x:3},{first:'Jane3',last:'Doe4',x:4}],

res = arr.reduce((acc, {first, x}) =>  x > 2 ? [...acc, {first, x}]:acc, []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Very elegant, now I understand it - took me a second to get `{first, x}`

Comment: I find this less readable then filter + map. I'm just curious to understand why you think this could be a better solution.

Comment: well, if there were 100 objects in the array, and 100 of those objects had an `x > 2`, then you would practically looping through the array twice, where as in this solution you would only loop through once. (so I think this is slightly more efficient - depending on the data set). But I'm not saying it is a better solution, its just _another_ solution

Comment: Once the sub parts are understood, it is as readable as the filter/map which seems like too much work.

Comment: Yes, I see now the accumulator is passed as first argument and the destructed object with only first and x  as second - need to grok this with more examples but yours is a good one

Comment: If I split it, it is easier: `res = arr.reduce(\n
  (acc, {first, x }) =>   x > 2 ? \n
  [...acc, {first, x}]: \n
  acc , \n
[]);` - it is one usecase perfectly suited for reduce

Comment: @mplungjan yeah, examples are always good. I think `[{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a:3}].map(({a}) => a)` might be a simpler example to wrap your head around. Mine's doing a similar thing just using another argument (acc in my case). Yeah, splitting up into multiple lines also makes it more readable I suppose :P

Answer (score 1):

Just concat the 2 functions

```js
const arr = [
  { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe', x: 1 },
  { first: 'Jane1', last: 'Doe1', x: 2 },
  { first: 'Jane2', last: 'Doe2', x: 3 },
  { first: 'Jane3', last: 'Doe4', x: 4 }
];          

const result = arr.filter(o => o.x > 2).map(o => ({first: o.first, x: o.x}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is fine to concat the two function, but What I am trying to ignore false records by putting some condtion inside  "let res = obj.map( o =>  { return  o.x > 2 && {  "first": o.first, "x": o.x  }  } )"

Comment: Because this is returning correct only it is also adding false records

Comment: What you mean by "adding false records"?

Comment: If you see the output of my "let res = obj.map( o =>  { return  o.x > 2 && {  "first": o.first, "x": o.x  }  } )" it is returing correct records with two false

Comment: In my solution there are no `false`. The first filter out unwanted objects (those with x <= 2) ah then maps the remaining objects to a new object with only the wanted fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to get a new array based on your criteria. This is useful since it does not modify your existing array.
You can then use map to modify the structure as shown.

```js
const arr = [{
    first: 'Jane',
    last: 'Doe',
    x: 1
  },
  {
    first: 'Jane1',
    last: 'Doe1',
    x: 2
  },
  {
    first: 'Jane2',
    last: 'Doe2',
    x: 3
  },
  {
    first: 'Jane3',
    last: 'Doe4',
    x: 4
  }
],

res = arr.filter(item => item.x > 2).map(({first,x}) => ({first,x}));
console.log(res);
```